# wxt terminal on gnuplot via cygwin

Tags: cygwin, gnuplot, wxwidgets, cairo, pango

How can I compile gnuplot on cygwin such that it will have the wxt terminal type? I have tried adding possible dependencies such as `libwx_gtk3u3.0_0`,`mingw64-x86_64-wxWidgets3.0`, `libcairo-devel`, `libpango1.0-devel`, and `mingw64-x86_64-pango1.0` while simultaneously reinstalling `gnuplot`, but gnuplot still says wxt is an unknown or ambiguous terminal type. Which packages do I need to install in cygwin to accomplish this? Can I accomplish this with the gnuplot package included with cygwin?

I believe the windows version of gnuplot uses wxt by default, but I wish to use gnuplot within a cygwin shell.

Comment: You mentioned installing *gnuplot* why building it?

Comment: try adding `libwx_gtk3u3.0-devel`

Comment: I have the same problem running gnuplot from cygwin after installation of the windows gnuplot "gp527-win64-mingw.exe".  The gnuplot I call from cygwin is /usr/bin/gnuplot (5.2 patchlevel 7) did work before and was installed before the windows gnuplot (5.2 patchlevel 4).